# How do you call game mode where the time is running out and player can increase time by collecting coins

Tags: game-mechanics, terminology

I am working on an arcade game and I want to make a game mode, where the player has some time to collect coins. When a coin is collected player gets extra time, so the game can continue infinitely. But when the time is run out the game ends.

I don't know how to name this game mode. Do you have any suggestions? Something like: Time attack?

Comment: How about "Time Trial"?

Comment: @Basic that could make a good answer, especially if you can link a couple of examples of games with a mode like this under that name, or references to others using the term that way to back it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it isn't required that you have "coins" and "a timer" then I've seen such modes called "Survival" modes with a few tweaks.

Simply replace the "coins" with some kind of heath pickup, and replace the "timer" with a slowly draining health bar. In fact, even without those changes "Survival Mode" still describes it pretty well.

If the timer is important (as in the case where speed running is encouraged or something like that), then "Time Trial" or "Time Attack" would both be fine, though they bring to mind finishing as fast as possible rather than lasting as long as you can.

If this isn't the primary mode of play in your game, then "Arcade Mode" would be a good fit as well.

Comment: Re: lasting as long as you can, it sounds like an "Endurance" mode